# I received this message [to/in] my inbox?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I received this message to my inbox?

or

> I received this message in my inbox?

I am having a difficult time deciding between these two. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 5):

The choice of preposition is governed by the verb that precedes it.

Messages come TO your inbox and are sent/dispatched TO your inbox, but they arrive IN your inbox and are received IN your inbox.

By the way, you were having difficulty **deciding** between the two, not "deciphering" between the two.

Comment: Oh boy, I feel like an idiot! Thanks for your help Ronald Sole.